# How to stop my vagrant box from updating?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I have the following entry in my *VagrantFile*:

`config.vm.box_check_update = false`

Which is what I found in the [Vagrant Docs](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/boxes/versioning.html) under the "AUTOMATIC UPDATE CHECKING" heading. To my surprise, however, my box updated and cleaned all my installed software and configuration.

What am I missing here? Why in the world have all my stuff disappeared even if the box was updated?

Comment: Amusingly, your question contains the answer I was looking for!  I had a paired down Vagrantfile, and wanted to enable this option, but couldn't remember what it was called exactly.  So, thanks for asking, even though you were asking a different question.  :)

Answer (score 1):

This option just configures checking for updates to notify you, it does not download them automatically. Furthermore, downloading updates does not overwrite any existing VM environments as noted in this question: [Update a Vagrant Box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914383/update-a-vagrant-box)

Therefore, something else must have caused your box to be updated and cleaned. Perhaps you ran, `vagrant destroy` followed by `vagrant init`?

Comment: thanks for the reply, I wanted to be clear here by what I meant when I said it cleared my stuff. I had installed some software on the box and as soon as I updated it, everything got wiped out except of course my code base which is in my local file system.

Comment: If the "machine" (in vagrant parlance) was re-built from the "box" (whether because it was updated, or not!), that would lose all your software installations.  I'd recommend you use "provisioning" to do all your software installations, and then they'll all come back even through a `vagrant destroy` / `vagrant up` cycle, or anything else that might cause the "machine" to be re-built.