# Update a Vagrant Box?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I have updated a box `vagrant box update` and now when I run `vagrant up` it boots into the old box. How can I update my box to use the newer version?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[From the Vagrant docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes/versioning.html#viewing-versions-and-updating):

> Finally, you can update boxes with `vagrant box update`. This will
>   download and install the new box. This will not magically update
>   running Vagrant environments. If a Vagrant environment is already
>   running, you'll have to ***destroy*** and *re*create it to acquire the new
>   updates in the box. The update command just downloads these updates
>   locally.

Comment: So I need to run `vagrant destroy` and then `vagrant up` ?

Comment: `vagrant reload` The equivalent of running a halt followed by an up.

Comment: reload wont do it.. you need destroy

Comment: Can I run `vagrant box update` in parallel when I already have a machine running? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42721065/can-i-use-vagrant-box-update-while-already-having-the-machine-running-by-vagr

Comment: I had to run `vagrant box remove laravel/homestead --box-version 1.1.0` so that `vagrant up` would then run the 4.0 version.

Comment: @Joe based on `vagrant box update -h`

> Updates the box that is in use in the current Vagrant environment,
if there any updates available. This does not destroy/recreate the
machine, so you'll have to do that to see changes.

Looks like we will need to destroy and up again.

Comment: To finally answer @Steven 's question: In my case yes. I ran `vagrant destroy` after looking up how to update the box without doing anything b4 that. `vagrant box update` did **not** work after that, it said the new box was not downloaded and it could not update to it. So I just ran `vagran up` and it downloaded the new box and provisioned it from scratch as expected.

Comment: To update a specific box you can use the `--box` argument. For example `vagrant box update --box archlinux/archlinux`.

Answer (score 0):

After a `vagrant box update` the system will have (at least) two boxes. You can see what's downloaded with `vagrant box list`.

To remove the old one(s) and use the new you can either do `vagrant box remove laravel/homestead --box-version x.y.z` as @Ryan said or issue a `vagrant box prune` command.

You'll be told

> Removing
> the box could corrupt the environment. We recommend destroying
> these environments first:
>
> homestead (ID: [...some string...])
>
> Are you sure you want to remove this box? [y/N]

Destroying a box will remove all the databases and other changes you've made, so be sure you've backed that up. Your Code directory is on your 'real' computer so is safe. (Tip: create a [cron job to back up your databases](https://gist.github.com/tleish/1c6e788c84f59200446b) to your Code directory, or use [Homestead's automatic database backup on destroy](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#database-backups)

In practice I rarely have to destroy a box so after removing the old box can issue a `vagrant up` or `vagrant reload --provision` command and get back to work.