# Can I use `vagrant box update` while already having the machine running by `vagrant up`?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead, vagrant-windows

I have some projects in Laravel, and when I have to give some maintenance to them, sometimes when I run `vagrant up`, it warns me up that I have a newer version of the laravel box, homestead, like the message below:

```
A newer version of the box 'laravel/homestead' is available! You currently
have version '1.1.0'. The latest is version '2.0.0'. Run
`vagrant box update` to update.
```

My question is, always when I run `vagrant box update`, it tooks like a decade to download the newer version of the box, because it seems like the hashicorp's servers are not too good enough to handle...

Having that in mind, can I give maintenance to my project while putting the machine up, and in parallel, also update the box? I really don't understand if that's really possible, or how could this impact the things.

Thank you very much, I hope to ask a question other users also have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Having that in mind, can I give maintenance to my project while putting the machine up, and in parallel, also update the box?

Yes - you can start your current VM running `vagrant up` and in parallel update the existing box `vagrant box update` (You can even do that from any folder, in this case point to the box to be updated `vagrant box update --box laravel/homestead`)

Note that the box is used to create the VM when you *first* spin up (vagrant is basically cloning the box to create a new VM) so if you update the box, it will not affect your current VM

As mentioned by others, if you want your VM to reflect the update of the box (3rd party software for example), then yes you need to destroy the VM and recreate the VM (running `vagrant up`)

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you very much. Exactly as I thought, but I'm really scare of updating the box from version 1.1.0 to 2.0.0, when I just need to do a simple maintenance to a project. The point is, is it "safe" somehow? Do I have the risk of losing time fixing any configuration or not? Specially when talking about Laravel applications, I know the guys change a lot the framework every minor version. Best regards to you!

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't update running machines.. Simply `update` command downloads the new image .. So if you really have to update a machine ( running or not ) you have to destroy it.

Check vagrant versioning [documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes/versioning.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've accepted @frédéric-henri's answer because it's more detailed explained exactly where I was in doubt, but thanks anyway, your answer complements the case very well. =)